# Nvidia drivers won't work in 16.04, /dev/fb0: Permission denied

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 16.04, nvidia-prime

Before 16.04 I had been using bumblebee but after upgrading ubuntu, nvidia drivers have broken again so I decided to use nvidia-prime instead. However it doesn't want to work, too. I get a black screen after bootup animation. It doesn't work even on a clean ubuntu installation. I tried it with both nvidia-361 and nvidia-340. I have disabled secure boot.

I get this error in Xorg.0.log:

```
[    22.545] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[    22.679] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

I saw some suggestions that I should make X run as root but I don't know if this is safe and won't break things later.

Comment: Does this work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions here is working for me:

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

I needed to install nvidia-364 from ubuntu-graphics ppa, I had also reinstalled Xorg before, so that also might be needed to do after an upgrade.